# How to make extension unionWith for Hashset

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to make an extension for the custom type. This is my code. I don't know how my source becomes zero in this code. Even in the debug part hashset temp is giving me a list of 10 logevents. But in the final the source is becoming zero.

```
public static void UnionSpecialWith(this HashSet<LogEvent> source, List<LogEvent> given,IEqualityComparer<LogEvent> comparer)
{
    List<LogEvent> original = new List<LogEvent>(source);
    List<LogEvent> second = given.Condense(comparer);

    source = new HashSet<LogEvent>(original.Condense(comparer),comparer);

    foreach (LogEvent logEvent in second)
    {
        if (original.Contains(logEvent, comparer))
        {
            int index = original.FindIndex(x => comparer.Equals(x, logEvent));
            original[index].filesAndLineNos.MergeFilesAndLineNos(logEvent.filesAndLineNos);
        }
        else
            original.Add(logEvent);
    }
#if DEBUG
    String content = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, original.Select(x => x.GetContentAsEventsOnly()));
    HashSet<LogEvent> temp = new HashSet<LogEvent>(original, comparer);
#endif
    source = new HashSet<LogEvent>(original, comparer);
}
```

Can anybody point me out  what is wrong?

**EDIT:**
     This is my custom type. Whenever I found a duplicate , I want to merge it's "filesAndLineNos" with the original one. This is what I am trying to achieve with the above code.

```
public class LogEvent 
{
    public String mainEventOriginal;
    public String subEventOriginal;
    public String mainEvent;
    public String subEvent;
    public int level;
    public Dictionary<String,HashSet<int>> filesAndLineNos;
}
```

The usage is something like

```
HashSet<LogEvent> required = new HashSet<LogEvent>(initialUniqueSet);
required.UnionSpecialWith(givenListOfLogEvents);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a matter of parameters being passed by value in .NET by default. You're changing the value of `source` to refer to a different `HashSet`, and that doesn't change the *caller's* variable at all. Assuming that `Condense` doesn't modify the list (I'm unaware of that method) your method is as pointless as:

```
public void TrimString(string text)
{
    // This changes the value of the *parameter*, but doesn't affect the original
    // *object* (strings are immutable). The caller won't see any effect!
    text = text.Trim();
}
```

If you call the above with:

```
string foo = "   hello   ";
TrimString(foo);
```

... then `foo` is still going to refer to a string with contents "   hello   ". Obviously your method is more complicated, but the cause of the problem is the same.

*Either* your extension method needs to modify the contents of the original `HashSet` passed in via the `source` parameter, *or* it should return the new set. Returning the new set is more idiomatically LINQ-like, but `HashSet.UnionWith` *does* modify the original set - it depends which model you want to be closer to.

EDIT: If you want to modify the set in place, but effectively need to replace the contents entirely due to the logic, then you might want to consider creating the new set, then clearing the old and adding all the contents back in:

```
public static void UnionSpecialWith(this HashSet<LogEvent> source,
                                    List<LogEvent> given,
                                    IEqualityComparer<LogEvent> comparer)
{
    List<LogEvent> original = new List<LogEvent>(source);
    List<LogEvent> second = given.Condense(comparer);

    foreach (LogEvent logEvent in second)
    {
        if (original.Contains(logEvent, comparer))
        {
            int index = original.FindIndex(x => comparer.Equals(x, logEvent));
            original[index].filesAndLineNos
                           .MergeFilesAndLineNos(logEvent.filesAndLineNos);
        }
        else
        {
            original.Add(logEvent);
        }
    }
    source.Clear();
    foreach (var item in original)
    {
        source.Add(item); 
    }
}
```

However, note:

- This does *not* replace the comparer in the existing set. You can't do that.
- It's pretty inefficient in general. It feels like a `Dictionary` would be a better fit, to be honest.

Comment: But doesn't "this" keyword ensures that I am operating on the source itself.

Comment: Can you show me how to change the content of the source code. Here I am not only trying to remove the duplicates. I am also adding the duplicat's members into the original one. Please see the edit.

Comment: @prabhakaran: `this` is just syntactic sugar - extension methods just mean that the compiler transforms `foo.Bar(baz)` into `ExtensionClass.Bar(foo, baz)`. That's *all* it does. The details of what you're trying to do are irrelevant - it's only the parameter handling which is important. I can't give you source code without knowing whether you're trying to change the contents of the existing `HashSet` object or whether you'd prefer to return a new one.

Comment: Changing the contents of the source itself enough for me.  But returning a new set will be a complement to the solution.

Comment: @prabhakaran: Well if you want to change the contents of the `source`, then do so - don't use `source = ...` within your method. The exact details of what you're doing elude me at this point, but just stick with the existing set, and add to that.

Comment: The main problem is I want to access the member in the hashset which is not possible. So that I am interchanging between hashset and list. If I get the solution for this then I can modify the source.

Comment: @prabhakaran: See my edit. Note that all those list checks are going to be pretty inefficient.